# Can SMS messages be traced when they come from a computer?

Tags: phishing, sms

From Amazon SNS, I can send SMS messages to any mobile phone.

To recipient phones, the SenderId is just a string of my choosing. The messages cannot be replied to.

I receive quite a few phishing messages that appear to be sent via a similar mechanism. I can't reply 'stop' and the sender ID is just a name.

Is it possible for network operators to trace these types of SMS messages back to their sender? Or is the inter-network protocol completely anonymous?

Comment: [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/g/gsm_sms.html) can trace pretty much anything that can be traced !

Comment: It can inspect anything going through _my_ computer, but I am concerned with what goes through the telecoms' infrastructure.

Comment: Anything can be traced within your reach of time and money you can put into it.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Data retention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_retention) requirement for various country telco. AWS SNS is simply a services proxy to SMS telco, so, no exception.

However, since it is a lucrative business for both telco and Phish spammer as [point out here](https://www.cloudmark.com/en/s/resources/whitepapers/the-true-cost-of-sms-spam), and it take expensive resources to track down and shutdown the operation, so you will not see the end of it.